# request-promise returns undefined but exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, httprequest, request-promise

Trying to do a request through request-promise but it's not working properly.

See the comment below.

Can somebody explain this PiA to me?

Thanks in advance

```
var todayOptions = { uri: `http://mlb.mlb.com/gdcross/components/game/mlb/year_${year}/month_${month}/day_${day}/master_scoreboard.json`, 
                     simple: false, 
                     resolveWithFullResponse: true
};

rp(todayOptions)
  .then(function (response){
    console.log(response.body); //RETURNS BODY
    console.log(response.body.data); //RETURNS UNDEFINED EVEN THOUGH IT EXISTS
 })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Assuming your data looks like this http://mlb.mlb.com/gdcross/components/game/mlb/year_2015/month_03/day_28/master_scoreboard.json, then you'd likely need to parse it first with JSON.parse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bet is `response.body` is a stringified JSON object. Try parsing it. request-promise returns a stringified object sometimes.

`console.log(JSON.parse(response.body).data);`

Answer (score 4):

You need set `json` option to true:

```
var todayOptions = { uri: `http://mlb.mlb.com/gdcross/components/game/mlb/year_${year}/month_${month}/day_${day}/master_scoreboard.json`, 
                     simple: false, 
                     resolveWithFullResponse: true,
                     json: true
};
```

Comment: Works as well, totally forgot about this option.

Was never mentioned in the request-promise docs but i always use it when using request;

In fact I always use request but I have to forEach + request now thus ended up with promises. I hate promises.

Comment: I was unaware of this option as well. Good to know., up voting.

Answer (score 0):

If this still doesn't work for you, as it didn't for me, try adding this to your options:

encoding: 'utf8'

That fixed everything for me. You don't even have to mess with json.parse or json.stringify compounding. The response is already a json object if you already have json: true in your options.